# Manga about a girl who was neglected by her own mother and did all the housework and ran away with a magician

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga before but I have forgotten the name.

The main character is a girl who lives with her mother, father, sister and brother. She is the oldest daughter and her family is poor. She is made to do all the housework because her mother, who came from a rich family, is lazy. The girl learnt how to clean and cook and other things from her aunt, her dad's sister. The girl wants to go to school, but her mother won't let her because they don't have the money. Problem is, the mother dotes on her youngest daughter and plans to send her to school instead. The main character is upset because she wanted to go to school.

One day she meets a man who can use magic, and he plans to help her because she possesses magic too. So the girl runs away with him to start a new life. When the dad finds out what's been happening from his sister, he feels regret for not helping his daughter, and the wife has no choice but to do the housework herself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Doshomin no Watashi, Jitsu wa Tenseisha Deshita](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/doshomin-no-watashi-jitsu-wa-tenseisha-deshita)*.

> I, Fiara, was born to a commoner father and a **mother of noble status**. From a young age, I was treated as a maid while my mother only **dotes on my younger sister**. No matter how hard I worked, I was **not allowed to advance in my studies** as well. “If so, I should just leave such a family...!!” After running away from home, on my way to the royal capital, **I met a magic user**, Zack, who changed my entire life.

The synopsis is pretty much a perfect match for the question. The mother is a former noble with poor magic and dotes on her younger daughter, forcing her elder daughter (the protagonist) to do the housework and eventually work to allow her favorite daughter to go to an all-girls school.